# PHP generated csv file is displaying Â£ for a UK pound sign (£) in Excel 2007

Tags: php, excel, csv, utf-8

I'm generating the csv file with the following header commands:

```
header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=utf-8; encoding=utf-8");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="products.csv"');
```

If I open the file in Excel 2007, then I get Â£ wherever a £ sign should appear. However, if I open the file in Notepad++, then the pound signs appear fine; similarly, if I change the content-type to text/plain and get rid of the attachement header, the pound signs appear correctly in the browser.

One strange thing is that if I go to the "Format" menu in Notepad++, it appears that the file is encoded in "UTF-8 without BOM". If I change this to "Encode in UTF-8", then save the file, the pound signs appear correctly in Excel. Is there a way to make it so that the file is saved in this encoding by PHP?

Comment: You need to show more details about the PHP script generating the file

Comment: I know UTF encoding for £ is &pound; could you just input pounds that way. I don't have experience in Excel, so this might be a useless comment ;)

Comment: UTF encoding for £ is not &pound; - that's HTML encoding. You can't use HTML encoding in CSV files.

Comment: @danixd - you're confusing UTF-8 with HTML Entities. &pound; is the HTML Entity for the pound sign: 0xC2 0xA3 is the UTF-8 byte sequence for the pound character.

Comment: @Mark Baker at least I was correct about the useless part ;) Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Output `0xEF 0xBB 0xBF` before emitting the CSV data. Don't forget to increase the content length header by 3 if you handle it.

```
header('Content-type: text/csv;');
header('Content-Length: ' + strlen($content) + 3);
header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=UK_order_' . date('Ymdhis') . '.csv');
echo "\xef\xbb\xbf";
echo $content;
exit;
```

Comment: What file does this need to be placed in?

Answer (score 11):

Use utf8_decode() - WORKED FOR ME

Comment: @AdrianEnriquez instead of `echo $csv_data;` do `echo utf8_decode($csv_data);`

Comment: This will fix your £ signs, but fail for € signs, because despite its very generic name, `utf8_decode` converts from UTF-8 to ISO 8859-1, which predates the adoption of the Euro. Converting to Windows-1252 instead (using `mb_convert_encoding`. `UConverter::transcode`. or `iconv`) would solve that, but still fail for many other characters that don't exist in that encoding. Signalling to Excel that the file is UTF-8 is a much better idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Nov 1962 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate('D,d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Content-Type: text/csv;');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$savename);
echo utf8_decode($csv_string);
```

Posted as above by user769889 but I missed it with my frustrations with this v-annoying issue, all fixed now and working. Hope this helps someone...

Comment: This will fix your £ signs, but fail for € signs, because despite its very generic name, `utf8_decode` converts from UTF-8 to ISO 8859-1, which predates the adoption of the Euro. Converting to Windows-1252 instead (using `mb_convert_encoding`. `UConverter::transcode`. or `iconv`) would solve that, but still fail for many other characters that don't exist in that encoding. Signalling to Excel that the file is UTF-8 is a much better idea.