# Putting £ symbol into excel from PHP?

Tags: php, excel, csv

I'm trying to insert a £ symbol into an .CSV file using PHP.

Currently I'm doing this

```
$list = array(
    array(
        $row["order_id"], 
        $c_client, 
        $c_media, 
        $row["insertion_date"],
        "£".$row["buy_cost"],
        $row["sell_cost"],
        $commsion_row_total,
        $media_percentage."%"
    )
);

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
```

This works fine, but the £ sign isn't working. Its showing up as the weird å symbol. I've tried lots of things but I can't work it out.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: Generally speaking, you wouldn't want to put the currency symbol in the field - it messes up sorting as a number.

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: That's all fine and good understanding encoding and character sets. But it's not giving me a solid solution here!

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [PHP generated csv file is displaying Â£ for a UK pound sign (£) in Excel 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076635/php-generated-csv-file-is-displaying-for-a-uk-pound-sign-in-excel-2007) it's a very similar issue.

the answer marked as correct states:

> Output 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF before emitting the CSV data. Don't forget to
>   increase the content length header by 3 if you handle it.

by using

```
echo `"\xef\xbb\xbf";
```

Please also make sure that you are using UTF-8 encoding

Comment: I've tried this and I just get some weird character instead of the £ symbol.