# Odd characters in csv for pound sign

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, character-encoding, symbols

I have written a function (in wordpress) to download csv file as below.

```
function download_csv(){

if( !empty($_GET['filename']) && !empty($_GET['downloadname']) && file_exists( trailingslashit( wsoe_upload_dir() ).$_GET['filename'].'.csv' ) && wsoe_is_shop_manager() ) {

    $download_filename = $_GET['downloadname'];
    $filename   = trailingslashit( wsoe_upload_dir() ).$_GET['filename'].'.csv';
    $charset = get_option('blog_charset');
    $settings = self::advanced_option_settings();

    $file = fopen( $filename, 'r' );
    $contents = fread($file, filesize($filename));
    fclose($file);

    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Encoding: '. $charset);
    header('Content-type: text/csv; charset='. $charset);
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$download_filename.csv");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Pragma: public");

    $fh = @fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );

    if( !empty($settings['wsoe_fix_chars']) ){

        /**
         * This is a fix for Microsoft Excel. It may happen that some weird characters
         * may appear while viewing the csv on excel with MAC OS.
         */

        $contents = mb_convert_encoding( $contents, 'UTF-16LE', $charset );
        $contents = chr(255) . chr(254).$contents; // Add byte order mark
    }

    fwrite( $fh, $contents );
    fclose($fh);
    exit();

   }
}
```

When csv is getting exported, pound sign (£) does not appear properly when viewing it. I've checked it in all editors including Excel, Notepad++, OpenOffice etc.

It is looking like this

[image: Currency symbol appears to be junk character]

Can anybody let me know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: What is the value of `blog_charset` from your `wp_options()` table

Comment: Check if the selected character encoding supports the pound sign. Also, make sure that you pick the same encoding in the spreadsheet software.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: It is UTF-8

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov: Yes, it does. In fact this issue does not occur when I export file on my local system (I have setup the site on local and tested it)

Comment: @Ankit, do you choose UTF-8 when you open it in OpenOffice? The software normally offers a list of available encodings before parsing the file.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov: Yes I do, but it didn't help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP generated csv file is displaying Â£ for a UK pound sign (£) in Excel 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076635/php-generated-csv-file-is-displaying-%c3%82%c2%a3-for-a-uk-pound-sign-%c2%a3-in-excel-2007)